# How to use Azure build pipeline queue-time variables

Tags: azure, yaml

I am trying to build an Azure build pipe that uses some calculated boolean flags.
But setting a variable to an expression does not appear to work.

```
variables:
  valueT1: true
  valueF1: false
  valueT2: ${{ true }}
  valueF2: ${{ false }}
  notT1: ${{ not(variables.valueT1) }}
  notF1: ${{ not(variables.valueF1) }}
  notT2: ${{ not(variables.valueT2) }}
  notF2: ${{ not(variables.valueF2) }}
```

I can ECHO all the variables back out using a script command:

```
- script: |
    echo valueT1: ${{ variables.valueT1 }}
    echo valueF1: ${{ variables.valueF1 }}
    echo valueT2: ${{ variables.valueT2 }}
    echo valueF2: ${{ variables.valueF2 }}
    echo notT1: ${{ variables.notT1 }}
    echo notF1: ${{ variables.notF1 }}
    echo notT2: ${{ variables.notT2 }}
    echo notF2: ${{ variables.notF2 }}
```

The variables echo as:

```
  valueT1: true
  valueF1: false
  valueT2: True
  valueF2: False
  notT1: False
  notF1: False
  notT2: False
  notF2: False
```

I expected both notF1 and notF2 to echo True.

The first two constants are lowercase - matching the assigned values.
The second two constants are capitalized - matching the evaluated Boolean names.
But why is the NOT expression failing?
I get the same results for any other expression, using NOT is just the simplest case.

Documentation indicates a False result could either be the actual boolean result or it could mean that the input value could not be parsed as a Boolean.  But the values are clearly Boolean when displayed.

**EDIT:**

Also tried:

```
notT1: ${{ not(variables['valueT1']) }}
(etc)
```

which produced identical output (all False).

And I tried the 'runtime evaluation' syntax:

```
notT1: $[ not(variables['valueT1']) ]
(etc)
```

which did not evaluate at all and produced:

```
notT1: $[ not(variables['valueT1']) ]
(etc)
```